# Different ways for aging steaks

Tags: meat, steak, aging

I'd like to know what techniques people have used for aging their steaks, i.e. dry or wet aging.

Comment: Steaks don't last in my house long enough to age!

Answer (score 4):

I use a sheet pan under a cooling rack. Put the steaks on the rack and then cover with paper towel and slide into the fridge. Check the towel each day or so and replace if wet.

I've used this method for both steaks and prime rib and it has worked very well.

Comment: Bottom shelf please!

Answer (score 1):

I have had good success with a really easy form of wet aging.  I just buy the steaks a week in advance and let the package set in the fridge unopened.  The next week, wash, pat dry, salt and a screaming hot grill.

This has worked excellent with the really thick boneless new york strip steaks I get at costco.  Also I take a trick from Jeffrey Steingarten and trim off the fat around the edge.  The allows me to put then on a screaming hot gas grill and leave it on high without the fat catching fire and burning everything.  5 min on one side, 1 or 2 on the other and that's it.  The crust is great on the side that you see and isn't that what is important?  I have never had success getting crust on both sides, either the steak is over done or there is no crust anywhere.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that whether you keep the meat in the packaging depends on how it is packed. You probably want to avoid this with styrofoam packed meats.