# Is there an aging process by which to "oak" meat?

Tags: meat, flavor, curing, dry-aging

I was hoping there might be more ideas [under this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1182/15), but I have been reading up on aging and curing meat and would like to know if there is some kind of process that, while aging the meat, can impart an oak flavor.

- Sorry, any answer cannot include any form of cooking the meat (i.e. smoking it with oak chips). This is strictly confined to prep

Although I haven't found anything to this effect, particular ideas might be a barrel-aging method for meat; i.e. white oak aging for Tabasco, oaked wines or liquors.

Comment: Would brining qualify? Never tried this but would speculate that a salt water and oak chip solution might accomplish your goal. No, it isn't 'dry aging' but it is 'prep'?

Comment: @Cos Brining and curing methods would qualify as not cooked

Comment: I won't call it an "answer" since I haven't tried it and I would suggest a small test. I will try this too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't see why you can't make oaked meat.  Corned beef and salt pork have been around for a long time.  The 'corn' referred to isn't actually corn, but is rock salt.  Here is a good starting point if you want to make oaked, corned beef which doesn't require refrigeration:

http://science.howstuffworks.com/innovation/edible-innovations/food-preservation5.htm

In the above article it specifically mentions barrels for storing the salted meat.

Try google with [salting meat].

Having read some research some years ago regarding the propagation of bacteria on artificial (plastic) and natural (wood) cutting boards, and the large difference in the ability of bacteria to grow on these two mediums, wood being by far the most bacteria resistant, it would seem at least prudent and in your case, desirable, to use wood containers.  Oak barrels are available in many sizes and you should be able to order them with removable covers with a bit of inquiry.

There is plenty of oak, in many forms, commercially available.  The explosion of wineries has produced many caterers to the makers of that product.

Here is a source for oak chips:

http://www.ibrew.com.au/html/equipment/oakbarrels/oakbarrels.html

Here is another source for all types of oak, including barrels:

http://www.stavin.com/index.htm

If you don't want to make the commitment of barrels, months long curing and the space requirements for same, you could simply buy some winery chips, brine your meat in the refrigerator with oak chips between layers of meat or surrounding a piece of meat.

Have fun!

Comment: sounds like it's worth a shot

Answer (score 3):

Liquid Smoke, you can use it as part of a rub or in a marinade or brine to infuse a rich smokey flavor to the meat as a pre-treatment. A Rub is most likely to get you the results you want.

note: I have hopes that using oak chips in a brine would work as well, this is an a quick solution to your question.

Comment: How is this more effective than cold smoking?